# pitch at too low?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, word-order

[Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pitch_2) has an example sentence under usage "pitch something (at something)"

**The test was pitched at too low a level for the students.**

I'm confused by the part of speech of "too low".

If "too low" modifies "pitched", I feel it should be "The test was pitched **too low** at a level for the students."

If "too low" modifies "a level", I feel it should be "The test was pitched at a level **too low** for the students."

As the usage required, after "at" is "something", but "too low" is not something. How am I supposed to understand it? Why is "too low" at its current place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a Big Mess Construction, so called because it is confusing for learners (and anyone who really thinks about it) as to why there's an indefinite article between an adjective and its noun. But it's idiomatic English.

There are only a few words that can appear at the start of this construction. It's always one of those words, followed by an adjective, followed by the indefinite article "a/an" followed by a noun (or noun phrase). Grammatically, these four words (or more if it's a noun phrase) go in the same spot in the sentence as a noun. The sentence "The test was pitched a level" is wrong; therefore "The test was pitched too low a level for the students" is also wrong. You can say it "was pitched at a level too low for the students". However, the difference grammatically is that you can't say "The test was pitched at a level too low", but you can say "The test was pitched at too low a level" (without "for...").

Here's a list of all the words that appear in this construction:

> a. She made *too rude* a remark (for me to repeat).
> b. She made *so rude* a remark (that we were shocked).
> c. I’ve never heard *as rude* a remark (as that).
> d. He doesn’t look the type to make *this rude* a remark.
> e. He doesn’t look the type to make *that rude* a remark.
> f. I wonder *how rude* a remark she could have made.
> g. Don’t be offended, *however rude* a remark she makes.
>
> — [The Big Mess Construction](http://web.stanford.edu/group/cslipublications/cslipublications/LFG/19/papers/lfg14arnoldsadler.pdf)

Comment: I've never heard of this. Thank you so much!